# uninitialized DWORD variable give random value?

Tags: c, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Uninitialized values being initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225788/uninitialized-values-being-initialized)

```
void Encrypt( FileContent *pFile )
{
    /* Get the key total ascii value */
    DWORD asciiKeyValue;

    for (DWORD i=0; i < pFile->keyLength; i++)
    {
        asciiKeyValue += pFile->encKey[i];
    }

    _tprintf(_T("[*]DEBUG The encKey ascii value is: %ld\n"), asciiKeyValue);
}
```

I am get an out put of `430` when `DWORD asciiKeyValue`, but once `DWORD asciiKeyValue = 0` is `230` which is as it should be.

Somebody has an explanation for that? Is the `asciiKeyValue` variable get a random value when it hasn't assigned an explicit value ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't "become" random. When you declare your `DWORD` it has whatever was in the memory at its address before. The memory is not *cleaned* unless you initialise it to something (like your 0).

Answer (score 4):

You don't ever initialise the value you only ever increment it. Therefore it will initially have any value which was last written to it.

If you had:

```
DWORD asciiKeyValue = 0; // Or any other value
```

Then you would get consistent results.

Answer (score 4):

You do not initialize `asciiKeyValue`. Values do not implicitly get initialized to 0 like they do in some other languages. You need to explicitly set your starting value. I would expect your code to be:

```
DWORD asciiKeyValue = 0;
```

This will yield predictable results.

It's like you bought a new picture frame from the store, and you are adding paint to it. In the end you might ask "Why is there a disfigured picture of a happy couple?? I did not paint that!" The solution is to replace the default random photo with a blank canvas.

Comment: Loved your frame-paint example.

Comment: _Automatic_ storage duration variables don't get initialised. Others (such as static storage ones) do.

Comment: True; actually now that I think about it, it's hard to summarize when variables are initialized and when they're not. But practically speaking, almost always if you rely on initialization, you should explicitly initialize. (ok now I'm running through the exceptions in my head ...)

Answer (score 1):

ever heard of **initialising of variables**. Well you have now :-)

```
DWORD asciiKeyValue = 0 ;
```

will solve your problem.